# how to use cosssim in gensim

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim

My questioon is about cossim usage.

I have this fragment of a very big fuction:

```
for elem in lList:
    temp = []
    try:
        x = dict(np.ndenumerate(np.asarray(model[elem])))
    except:
        if x not in embedDict.keys():
            x = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=300)
            embedDict[elem] = x
        else:
            x  =  dict(np.ndenumerate(np.asarray(embedDict[elem])))

    for w in ListWords:
        try:
            y =  dict(np.ndenumerate(np.asarray(model[w])))
        except:
            if y not in embedDict.keys():
                y = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=300)
                embedDict[w] = y
            else:
                y =  dict(np.ndenumerate(np.asarray(embedDict[w])))

        temp.append(gensim.matutils.cossim(x,y))
```

I get the following exception:

```
File "./match.py", line 129, in getEmbedding
    test.append(gensim.matutils.cossim(x,y))
  File "./Python_directory/ENV2.7_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/matutils.py", line 746, in cossim
    vec1, vec2 = dict(vec1), dict(vec2)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Can you please help me and explain to me what this exception means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments of [gensim.matutils.cossim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html) are expected to be of type `list of (int, float)` but you are using dictionaries.

The exception happens in the `cossim` function with the following [cossim implementation](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/matutils.py#L787):

```
vec1, vec2 = dict(vec1), dict(vec2)
```

With the correct type, `dict(vec)` works:

```
dict([(1, 2.), (3, 4.), (5, 6.)])
```

But if you do not provide the correct type, it throws the exception, for instance with:

```
dict([1, 2, 3])
```